# Entry to the US with an expired Nexus

Tags: nexus, customs-and-immigration

Is it possible to enter the US through the Nexus lane while my Nexus card is being renewed? And how?

Comment: You can for up 6 months, but not by air (if not using a passport), for which the card must be valid

Answer (score 11):

According to the [CBP website](https://help.cbp.gov/), you can use an Expired NEXUS card, provided you have submitted your renewal, for up to 6 or 12 months after expiry. The grace period is normally 6 months, but as of December 2019 CBP has extended it to 12 months.

> If you submitted a renewal application before expiration of your
>   current membership, then you can continue to use your benefits until
>   the renewal is finalized (up to 6 months after your expiration date).
>   [CBP "I have submitted my Trusted Traveler application for review. Did CBP receive my application?"](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1332?language=en_US)

As of December 2019, the [Dashboard](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/dashboard) of the Trusted Traveler Program website says,

> Due to a significant increase in application volume, we are extending 
>   the grace period from 6 months to 1 year for any submitted renewal
>   application. This means you will continue to receive full benefits
>   for 1 year while U.S. Customs and Border Protection is finalizing your
>   renewal application.…

This note then links to a popup document *How do I renew my Trusted Traveler (Global Entry, NEXUS, SENTRI or FAST) membership?*, without a clear URL. This popup document says,

> …If you submit a renewal application before your membership expires,
>   you will be able to continue to use benefits up to 1 year after your
>   membership expiration date.…

Comment: The first sentence slightly mischaracterizes the quoted material, since it omits the requirement that the renewal be submitted before expiration.  I did not cast the downvote.  I find unexplained downvotes vexing.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not.  You are permitted to renew as early as one year prior to expiry so there is no need to leave renewal to the last minute.

You can, however, use a non-NEXUS lane as usual, using your passport or other WHTI-compliant identification.

Comment: A reference would improve this answer.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it appears to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your NEXUS card for up to 6 months past the expiration date just as Jason said.  So long as you submitted your renewal application before it expired.  Here is the link that gives you that information. https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1332/~/i-have-submitted-my-trusted-traveler-application-for-review.-did-cbp-receive-my

Answer (score 1):

The links above no longer work - here is the new link https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1332?language=en_US - note that the article calls out that you an use your card for up to 6 months if you apply to renew it before it expires.

Comment: You can (and should) edit the post that has a broken link.

Comment: I have proposed such an edit to @Jason's answer.