# Does Nexus renewal grace period apply to enter Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, paperwork, nexus

I see where the grace period allows me to access the US with my Nexus for up to a year now. Does the grace period apply to entering Canada?

Comment: It's worth noting that a NEXUS holder may take advantage of the grace period only if a renewal application has been filed before the card's expiration date. See: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111444/entry-to-the-us-with-an-expired-nexus/125113#125113

Answer (score 2):

The [CBSA website](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/services/covid/changes-changements-eng.html#s3) recognizes the 18-month extension, so it may be assumed that NEXUS members who qualify for the 18-month extension will also continue to be treated as active members north of the border.

In addition, I spoke on the phone with one of the Canadian NEXUS offices at 1-800-842-7647 on Dec 1. They explained that if a person has submitted a renewal application prior to expiration and is within the 18-month grace period:

- The NEXUS card will continue to be accepted at the kiosks, since the kiosks are able to determine that the membership is still active;
- Airport staff will be aware of the 18-month grace period and should allow members to use the NEXUS security lanes, although it is advisable to carry a print-out of the renewal application receipt just in case they want to see it.