# Nexus renewal application grace period

Tags: nexus

If I applied for renewal after the expiration date, is there still some kind of grace period while i wait?  I know that there is a 6-12 month grace period when you apply before your NEXUS expires, however, I am wondering about if it has already expired.

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus grace period only comes into force if a renewal request is filed before the date of expiration. See the first CBP quote in the answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111444/entry-to-the-us-with-an-expired-nexus). It says:

> If you submitted a renewal application before expiration of your current membership, then you can continue to use your benefits until the renewal is finalized (up to 6 months after your expiration date).

The six-month period has subsequently [been increased to twelve months](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/dashboard):

> Due to a significant increase in application volume, we are extending the grace period from 6 months to 1 year for any submitted renewal application. This means you will continue to receive full benefits for 1 year while U.S. Customs and Border Protection is finalizing your renewal application.…

With thanks to @Jason for the previous answer.