# Due to COVID, Nexus does not allow me to continue with renewal until 7/6/20. How can I file for a grace period?

Tags: covid-19, nexus

Due to COVID, Nexus does not allow me to continue with renewal until 7/6/20. How can I file for a grace period (my Nexus expires 1 day after 7/6/2020)?

In addition, how do I confirm whether my renewal request has been accepted?

Comment: Do you mean the web site will not let you schedule an appointment? Or it will only give you dates after July 6?

Comment: There's no such thing as "filing for a grace period," there is only filing for a NEXUS renewal. Having filed a request to renew your NEXUS membership, you can continue to use the NEXUS lanes for twelve additional months, even before you've received your new NEXUS card.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to apply separately for a grace period, as if you have filed for renewal **before expiry** you automatically get a 6 month grace period (which is currently a 12 month grace period due to processing and Covid-19 delays).

From the CBP Help Q&A [I have submitted my Trusted Traveler application for review. Did CBP receive my application?](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1332?language=en_US):

> *If you submitted a renewal application before expiration of your current membership, then you can continue to use your benefits until the renewal is finalized (up to 6 months after your expiration date).*

See also this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/125113/40422) to [Entry to the US with an expired Nexus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111444/entry-to-the-us-with-an-expired-nexus)

Additionally I have found a number of reports that the grace period for *Global Entry* has been extended out to 18 months, however I haven't found anything official or that says this also extends to NEXUS or SENTRI.  See [18 Month Global Entry Renewal Grace Period](https://onemileatatime.com/global-entry-grace-period/)

Comment: https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/services/covid/changes-changements-eng.html